# Can't close Visual Studio Code Window with my shortcut, yet it works for tabs

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In apps I use, I like to use the command <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> to close tabs and to close windows when there are no open tabs.

I tried to do the same for Visual Studio Code by searching for the commands with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and replacing them in my keybindings.json file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>.

Those are the first two elements in my keybindings.json below.

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
  { "key": "ctrl+cmd+left",                 "command": "workbench.action.closeWindow",
                                            "when": "!editorIsOpen" },
  { "key": "ctrl+cmd+left",                 "command": "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor" },
  { "key": "ctrl+cmd+right",                "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile" }
]
```

I can close tabs with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>. I think that means the 2nd command is working. The 3rd one above for opening tabs with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> works too.

However I cannot close the window with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>, which I'm pretty sure means that the first command isn't working. Yet, I can still close the window with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

Why can't I close a window with no tabs open with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>? Why does it still work for <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>?

EDIT: I was able to get things to work as I wanted by changing the order of the first two shortcuts. I haven't figured out why that works yet and would appreciate it if someone could answer that. I suspect there's some sort of cascading esque feature that causes the 2nd command to overwrite the first command and the when condition prevented that from happening with the order reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Keybinding rules in Visual Studio Code are evaluated from the bottom to the top. So it starts with your custom rules in your keybindings.json file and goes through the default rules. The first keybinding rule that matches your key and meets its when condition is applied. [See the VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

As a result, when I tried to close a window it would always match the keybinding to close an active window. Switching the order of the first two commands above resolves the problem because now when I try to close a window it matches the when condition of the editor is not open. Additionally, when I'm trying to close a tab it doesn't match the condition of the editor is not open so it looks up to the next rule (which has no when condition limiting the scope of the rule) and closes the active editor.

So Visual Studio Code actually "cascades" from bottom to top.